# Should I create an exception object in an initializer or code it in every method?

Tags: c#, exception, refactoring

In my Service classes I create an exception instance like this:

```
protected ServiceException _ex;

protected void Initialize()
{
    _ex = new ServiceException();
}
```

Later in these classes I call this exception if something goes wrong:

```
    public void Delete<T, V>(T item, V repo)
        where T : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
        where V : IAzureTable<T>
    {
        try
        {
            repo.Delete(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ex.Errors.Add("", "Error when deleting " + typeof(T).Name.ToLower());
            throw _ex;
        }
    }
```

Outside of this in the controller I check for the exception:

```
    catch (Exception e) { log(e); }
```

Then I handle this:

```
    protected void log(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is ServiceException)
        {
            ModelState.Merge(((ServiceException)ex).Errors);  
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.Write(ex);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the long example but what I would like to know is if this is a valid thing for me to be doing. In particular someone commented that I am creating a new value of _ex every time even if there's no exception. Well my reason for doing this was that each controller has about twenty try-catch blocks and I thought it better to just create an _ex object at the start and so not have to have twenty areas where I create a new _ex if something goes wrong. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me if this all makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest collecting errors in a separate structure and then just passing it in the exception class constructor whilst throw so you do not create an instance of exception class unless really need it:

```
// class constructor, List of strings or any entity like ErrorEntry
IList<string> errors = new List<string>();

// collect while execution
errors.Add(errorText);    

// raise an exception
throw new ServiceException(this.errors);
```

BTW, can you give some examples when you track an error but do not raising an exception?

Comment: Thansk for pointing to this, feel free editing answers yourself if found such a typo or misprint

Comment: I can't do 1-char edits, and I didn't want to change anything else... so I thought it quicker to let you know in a comment and then delete it ;)

Comment: Right, this is a true. Thanks!

Comment: There is no time when I find an error and don't raise an exception that is handled in the controller. All the actions of the service layers are inside of try -- catch in the controllers.  I think your suggestion looks good and I will look into implementing that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The exception is not really part of the persisted internal state of the class, it describes nothing about the class, does not really help the class do what it needs to do, it is simply a bad side effect that can happen while the class is performing its normal function. To that end, it doesn't need to be in the held state of the class. Simply create it when you need it.

As for your concern about possibly creating this in 20 different places, perhaps this should lead you to question why the class has 20 different things it is doing. Are all of these things logically related? Or is your class really a collection of many classes that simply haven't been declared as such?

(That being said, if the manner of creating the exception is common in each case, you can certainly refactor the creation into a reusable method/class of its own.)

Answer (score 1):

I would not do that:

- if (when) you start using multiple threads this will get pretty ugly when 2 exceptions happen at about the same time.
- when 2 exceptions happen sequentially how do you expect cleanup to happen? Is every place where you handle the exception is expected to do its own cleanup?
- What if one holds on to the exception and more information is added or replaces to the only instance before one have chance to handle it?

The similar approach is used in Win32 API (`SetLastError`) and in some runtime libraries (i.e. `errno` in C). In my opinion it makes error handling hard.

Recomendation - if you want to give caller more information about errors - collect information during the operation and report it in a newly created exception. Note that "operation" may mean several calls to a service, but caller still consider it a single action. I.e. OpenFile, WriteData, CloseFile can be cinsdered single operation by caller, also it may be better to refator each operation to single call.